# How do you get out of the Windows bad update nightmare?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

My (HP) Windows 7 box is showing the "Not Genuine" warning.  I see that this is because of a bad update and the "fix update" KB3024777 has failed something like 30 times with "unknown error"   Tried downloading it and running it manually but after the "do you want to run this" dialog nothing happens.  It essentially just dies.

How do you get out of this Microsoft nightmare?

Answer (score 0):

Run as administrator:

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:3004394 /quiet /norestart
dism.exe /online /remove-package /packagename:Package_for_KB3004394~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0 /quiet /norestart
```

way 2: [Windows not genuine errors.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3024777)

Need reboot.